# How could I achieve a C++ virtual function in Rust?

Tags: struct, rust

This is the definition of a virtual function in C++, and it is essentially what I am trying to do in Rust:

> A virtual function is a member function that you expect to be
>   redefined in derived classes. When you refer to a derived class object
>   using a pointer or a reference to the base class, you can call a
>   virtual function for that object and execute the derived class's
>   version of the function.

I have a struct `Foo` that contains some bytes.

I want to assign a helper struct to `Foo`; there can be many different types of helpers, (`Helper1`, `Helper2`, etc.) but each one has the same layout. Each helper will always have a `read()` function that reads bytes from `Foo`, but they will all return slightly different values based on their own calculations (hence the need for multiple different structs). The helper that I choose to assign to `Foo` will be determined at runtime, but I want to include some type of "generic helper struct" to satisfy the compiler. The generic helper will be replaced with a specific helper struct after I determine which helper to use at runtime.

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
pub struct Foo {
    bytes: Vec<u8>,
    helper: GenericHelper???
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn set_helper(&mut self, arg1: i32) {
        match arg1 {
            1 => {
                self.helper = DerivedHelperA;
            }
            2 => {
                self.helper = DerivedHelperB;
            }
            _ => {
                self.helper = DerivedHelperDefault;
            }
        }
    }

    // Called after set_helper()
    pub fn read(&self, arg1: usize) -> u8 {
        //helper.read() will call the re-defined read() function in the derived class
        self.helper.read(arg1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, trait or trait objects can be used in this situation, which does the pretty much as your requirement.

Comment: Have you read the [OOP section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-00-oop.html) of the 2nd edition of the Rust book? Its 2nd part (Trait Objects) is exactly about "virtual" functions.

Comment: For the *specific* example, you can [also use function pointers](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=37d926755a17960407f5bd6f8769a5ea&version=stable).

Comment: [Boxed trait objects](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=0137af66e07752262cc9b702357e39c9&version=stable) are also a solution.

Comment: @Shepmaster the boxed trait approach worked for me, thank you!!